# PowerShell error: computer name invalid in custom function

Tags: function, powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I am trying use Read-Host -Prompt to fill out multiple server names and user account names, and then pass those into the invoke-command to complete the task - which is to make someone local admin. 
I am unable to figure out why PowerShell throws me this error:
"One or more computer names are not valid. If you are trying to pass a URI, use the -ConnectionUri parameter, or pass URI objects instead of strings.".

In addition, I am also getting the error:

> "Add-LocalGroupMember : Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object."

Code example below:

```
if ($OptPrompt -eq 1) { 

    $prompt1 = Read-Host -Prompt 'Test Accounts'

    $prompt1.Split(",")

    $prompt1_1 = Read-Host -Prompt 'Test Servers'

    $prompt1_1.Split(",")

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $prompt1_1 -ScriptBlock {Add-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Administrators' -Member $Using:prompt1} 

}
```

More info:

Servers are online

Servers have "-" in them, for example, "Server-22-test"

Servers are responding to ping (hostname and IP address)

Using Invoke-Command on its own works, but not inside the function

There is no firewall or security blocking the account(s) in question

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `$prompt1_1.Split(",")` does not update `$prompt1_1`. It only outputs the split method result. You need `$prompt1_1 = $prompt1_1.Split(",")` first. The same applies for `$prompt1 = $prompt1.Split(",")`

Comment: You can make your variables as descriptive as you want, and the guidance, generally, is that you should!  I'd rename those variables to $testAccounts and $testServers.  Also, @AdminOfThings was right on the money, you need to recommit the variable, like so.  `$testAccounts = $testAccounts.Split(",")`

Comment: This has fixed my issue. Also, figured out later that becasue of the .Split(",") I had to enter my server names as is - without quotes - to get the script to work. Something new I learned today. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you are expecting `$prompt1` and `$prompt1_1` to contain comma-delimited names. By using `Read-Host` to populate the variables, they will be type `String`. You will need to rely on users to enter the comma separators manually with your code. With that said, executing the `.Split()` method on a String object does not update the String object. You must either update the variable assignment or pass the method outputs as expressions into `Invoke-Command`.

```
# Method 1: Reassigning Variable Before Invoke-Command
if ($OptPrompt -eq 1) { 
    $prompt1 = Read-Host -Prompt 'Test Accounts'
    $prompt1 = $prompt1.Split(",")
    $prompt1_1 = Read-Host -Prompt 'Test Servers'
    $prompt1_1 = $prompt1_1.Split(",")
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $prompt1_1 -ScriptBlock {Add-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Administrators' -Member $Using:prompt1} 
}


# Method 2: Passing Expressions into Invoke-Command
if ($OptPrompt -eq 1) { 
    $prompt1 = Read-Host -Prompt 'Test Accounts'
    $prompt1_1 = Read-Host -Prompt 'Test Servers'
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $prompt1_1.Split(",") -ScriptBlock {Add-LocalGroupMember -Group 'Administrators' -Member ($using:prompt1).Split(",") } 
}
```

The advantage of using expressions is your original variables remain unchanged.